# ngResource: Promise not Resolved

Tags: json, angularjs, ionic-framework, ngresource

Let's say a Service like this:

```
.factory('GetPaths', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/paths/coord/:lat/:long', 
       {lat: "@lat" }, {long: "@long" } , 
       {
         get:    {method: 'GET' , isArray: true },  
      }

   );
})
```

it gets called like this:

```
scope.paths = GetPaths.get({'lat':1},{'long':1});
```

I get the following response:

```
{"long":1,"$promise":{},"$resolved":false}
```

When I use cURL on my backend, I get this JSON Array:

```
[
  {
    "pathid":"1",
    "title":"Pathest",
    "eta":"3:00",
    "TYPE":"Hike",
    "difficulty":"Hard",
    "distance_in_km":"0"
 }
]
```

**My Question is:** How to retrieve the same JSON Array as data to populate my list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue with $resource configuration. Should be:

```
return $resource('/paths/coord/:lat/:long', 
   {lat: '@lat', long: '@long' } , 
   { get: { method: 'GET', isArray: true } }
);
```

And in your case you can just use `query` instead of `get` and leave out third argument at all. Check out [$resource docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).

Comment: is it normal that my log now returns an empty response?

Comment: Just to be sure, after applying the fix to config you're doing the call to api like `GetPaths.query({ lat: 1, long: 1 })`?

Comment: Yes. my new code is available here [JS Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/h3yV0xQ2) you can call the API on [API Sample Call](http://p-express.ddns.net/ike/v1/paths/coord/1/1)

Comment: Yes, it's probably fine because `$resource` is asynchronous. You can check if data becomes available to the controller, e.g. by outputting `<pre>{{ paths | json }}</pre>` in the template.

Comment: Or use alternative callback syntax for $resource: `GetPaths.query({'lat':1,'long':1}, function (data) { $scope.paths = data; console.log('pats', data); });`

Comment: I tried the Alternative Callback Syntax, the log is empty (i.e. data is never available for the controller?)

Comment: my JavaScript Console gives this `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://p-express.ddns.net/ike/v1/paths/coord/1/1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: You need CORS to be configured on the API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes Actually from My Browser's CORS Security.
it could be disabled through opening chrome with:

```
--args --disable-web-security
```